# What is the term used for how many microns or nm for lithography used on silicon wafer?

Tags: semiconductors

I think as of 2019 it is said that 7 nm is the smallest possible? I wonder how much it was in 2010, 2000, and 1995 (it was micron instead of nm earlier). I hope to find the historical chart / data but don't know what term is used for the length of lithography?

Comment: What do you mean by "how many microns" ? Did you even search? Probably you mean: What is the minimum **feature size** of an IC manufacturing process. A quick search will reveal that 7 **nano meter** (not "micron") is currently in (early) production. Search for "process node feature size" and look here: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/technology_node

Comment: I searched and got history of Micron Inc, and mostly irrelevant charts. The best I could find was https://images.app.goo.gl/TdGVpASLUuz6XuwS9 but the PDF document is missing

Comment: it seems 7 micron was possible even in the year 1976 and 1977... the term I heard was 7 奈米 and yes... it should be 7 nanometer, and nm is 1/1000 of a micron

Comment: I've read of Intel's guys, who started out at Fairchild, speaking of 100 micron or 0.1 millimeter as approximately the resolution of their early photo-graphic lense systems. Remember the Fairchild guys had to **INVENT** every thing needed: optics, chemistry, etching, deposition, etc. In the very first Integrated Circuits, they used the optics from twin-lense-reflex cameras.

Comment: I suggest you search through the old conference proceedings of the IEEE Solid State Circuits conference. Papers at this conference regularly discussed the limits of photolithography.

Comment: Did you do any research at all? The Wikipedia entry for [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) has just such a chart right at the top, starting with 10 um in 1971.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia's Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) and [Semiconductor Device Fabrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_device_fabrication), it looks like the formal term for such length is called "minimum feature size", "technology node", or "semiconductor manufacturing process":

> By industry standard, each generation of the semiconductor
>   manufacturing process, also known as "technology node", is designated
>   by the process’s minimum feature size. Technology nodes, also known as
>   "process technologies" or simply "nodes", are typically indicated by
>   the size in nanometers (or historically micrometers) of the process's
>   gate length.

Each of the articles has the sizes or lengths listed, with the label "Semiconductor
manufacturing
processes":

```
10 µm – 1971
6 µm – 1974
3 µm – 1977
1.5 µm – 1981
1 µm – 1984
800 nm – 1987
600 nm – 1990
350 nm – 1994
250 nm – 1996
180 nm – 1999
130 nm – 2001
90 nm – 2003
65 nm – 2005
45 nm – 2007
32 nm – 2009
22 nm – 2012
14 nm – 2014
10 nm – 2016
7 nm – 2018
5 nm – 2019
3 nm – ~2021
```

And such chart can be found by Googling for images of "Feature Size History":
[image]